# Twilio Conversations API - Reply like in WhatsAPP

Tags: whatsapp, reply, twilio-conversations

We're in the middle of a PoC to build a Chat App using Twilio Conversations API.

We have almost all what we need so far, although I haven't found a way to implement the `Reply` feature like in WhatsApp:

[image]

But what we get in our Chat screen is only the message response:

[image]

And within the JSON response after getting the message I didn't find an attribute to identify this.

Is it possible to implement this feature with the Conversations API? Does anyone have a suggestion to build this?